# Append svg element content using innerHTML in Google graph

Tags: svg, append, innerhtml

I like to add two images to form a single image and save it. when trying to save, it is either saving a single image. So i am trying to accomplish adding the image to a single image as follows:

```
  function getImgData(chartContainer) {
            var chartArea = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].parentNode;
            var chartArea1 = chartContainer.getElementsByTagName('svg')[1].parentNode;

               var svg = chartArea.innerHTML + chartArea1.innerHTML;
              var doc = chartContainer.ownerDocument;
              var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
              var  cwidth = chartArea.offsetWidth + chartArea1.offsetWidth;
              var cheight = chartArea.offsetHeight + chartArea1.offsetHeight;
              canvas.setAttribute('width',cwidth );
              canvas.setAttribute('height',cheight );

              canvas.setAttribute(
                                'style',
                                'position: absolute; ' +
                                'top: ' + (-cheight* 2) + 'px;' +
                                'left: ' + (-cwidth  * 2) + 'px;');
                  doc.body.appendChild(canvas);
                  canvg(canvas, svg);
                  var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                  canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
                  return imgData;
           }
```

But it didnt add up and only first image is displaying. Please suggest.